# How to do sudo grep in a bash script?

Tags: bash, debian, grep, sudo

I would like to check if the given ip address is already in the config file. But /etc/ can only be accessed by root, and I'm running the a script as a user and not as root. It seems I can't just combine sudo with grep.

```
#!/bin/bash
CLIENT_WG_IPV4="10.66.66.1"

DOT_EXISTS=$(sudo grep -c "$CLIENT_WG_IPV4/22" "/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf")
if [[ ${DOT_EXISTS} == '0' ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

I get the error message:

> grep: /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf: Permission denied

What can I do?

Comment: "_I'm running the a script as admin_" do you mean you're running it as `root`? If so, the `sudo` should be unnecessary

Comment: Please show us the output of `sudo ls -l /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 130 Nov 14 18:17 /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` It needs root permission. I'm running as a user (admin).

Comment: @Houman Your `ls` command shows that the file is readable by everyone.  What are the permissions on `/etc/wireguard`? (`ls -ld /etc/wireguard`)

Comment: `drw------- 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 18:40 /etc/wireguard` No, only root can access it. I'm not root.

Comment: What does "admin" mean on your system? It does not mean "root"?

Comment: Just a plain user that is called admin. I have updated the question.

Comment: `But /etc/ can only be accessed by root` incorrect ... it's `/etc/wireguard` that can only be read by root